# How to remove items from list that don't contain a certain character

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list that looks like this

```
/listing/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-boyasiz-2016-passat-variant-1.6-tdi-dsg-higline-sunroof-hayalet-819608311/detail,#,#,,/listing/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-boyasiz-2016-passat-variant-1.6-tdi-dsg-higline-sunroof-hayalet-819608311/detail,https://eminefeegehan.sahibinden.com/en/,#,#....
```

I want to remove everything that doesn't contain the word listing. I know of a one liner function

```
_.without(arr, '#')
```

but it only removes # and leaves the null item there. I want list's length to reduce if the item is removed from there. Moreover using this won't let me remove items that have https:

Comment: use Regular Expressions

Comment: Does _.without work well with that? what about the issue of leaving null item in its placewe

Comment: ^(https?://|#)  does this seem correct? @cybercoder

Comment: But its not working :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood you correctly, that might help you.

```
var arr = ['/listing/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-boyasiz-2016-passat-variant-1.6-tdi-dsg-higline-sunroof-hayalet-819608311/detail','#','#','','/listing/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-boyasiz-2016-passat-variant-1.6-tdi-dsg-higline-sunroof-hayalet-819608311/detail','https://eminefeegehan.sahibinden.com/en/'];

var results = arr.filter(function(item){return item.indexOf(/listing/) !== -1});

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove multiple elements from an array you can use filter function with your own logic.

```js
const items = ['/listing/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-boyasiz-2016-passat-variant-1.6-tdi-dsg-higline-sunroof-hayalet-819608311/detail','#','#',,'/listing/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-boyasiz-2016-passat-variant-1.6-tdi-dsg-higline-sunroof-hayalet-819608311/detail','https://eminefeegehan.sahibinden.com/en/','#','#']
const valueToRemove = '#'
const filteredItems = items.filter(item => (item !== valueToRemove && item.indexOf(/listing/) !== -1))
console.log(filteredItems);
```

Comment: It is not entire removing it. For instance if I remove # then resultant list looks like  /listing/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2016-model-vw-passat-1.6-tdi-dsg-comfortline-boyasiz..masrafsiz-835384488/detail,,/listing/vasita-otomobil-volkswagen-2016-model-vw-passat-1.6-tdi-dsg-comfortline-boyasiz..masrafsiz-835384488/detail,https://altrakotomotivmanisa.sahibinden.com/en/

Comment: There are empty spaces

Comment: Nevermind, I added another filter function to the resultant output

Comment: And how do I remove https:// with it? how do I check whether a string starts with it or not?

Comment: .filter(item => item !==new RegExp("https:\/\/|#") This isn't working

Comment: Updated the answer, and it works exactly as you wanted. I am not sure why you are saying it gives null element. If you try 'run code snippet', you can see the results here

Comment: If you run the code snippet, it only removes https:// part from the entire link and not the entire link. I need a list that only contains items that start with /listing

Comment: Updated the answer again. Please check now. Next time you request some answers, please add all these points upfront, or enhance the code yourself by using the answers are starting point.

Comment: I would suggest to choose the below answer as accepted if your expectation is only that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589160/409315

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `splice` method and `indexof` method of array

```
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

const valueToRemove = 'c'
const index = array.indexOf(valueToRemove);
if (index > -1) {
  array.splice(index, 1);
}

// array = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f']
console.log(array);
```